# OneLogin OIDC OpenID-Connect

Tags: openid, onelogin

I am interested in Onelogin OIDC, but would like so see how well it has worked out for mobile applications and web sites.

Do you know of any mobile applications and/or websites currently using Onelogin OpenID-Connect?

Answer (score 1):

Right now OneLogin supports OIDC via per-customer configured connections, so we don't have a lot of visibility on what sorts of apps are being configured.

Having said that, if the application supports a web-based authentication flow of either the Implicit or Authentication flow, you should be good to go.

The only caveat is that OneLogin doesn't (yet) support redirecting to localhost, so self-contained, native apps will not be able to get the redirect request unless they have a hosted component on the web.